# CouchBase Lite Replication between two local dbs over https

Tags: https, couchbase-lite

I couldn't find any info in CouchBase Lite documentation. We have two .net MVC websites with embedded CouchBase lite dbs. I had replication setup and running over http without Sync Gateway. However, we would like to secure the link with https...  Anyone has done that before?

Thanks,
HS

Comment: Are you the one I responded to on our forums?

Comment: If not here's the forum link https://forums.couchbase.com/t/couchbase-lite-replication-over-https/6496/20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank Laurent Doguin for posting the link.  Borrrden answered my questions on Chouchbase forum. I couldn't mark your posts as answer so here is the link again just to complete the post.

https://forums.couchbase.com/t/couchbase-lite-replication-over-https/6496